# Opening a windows application like a game or a browser or any other program with c++

Tags: c++, process, windows

I was wondering that how can i open any application in windows by using c++ programming, i am using dev c++. I used `system()` but it is not performing well or i am not using it correctly. Kindly tell me the syntax of `system()` to open an application or tell another function.

Answer (score 4):

Use shell execute instead of system for windows.

```
#include <Windows.h>
//Link with library: Shell32.lib  or  libshell32.a

ShellExecute(
   NULL,            //handle to the parent window
   "open",          //Action to take 
   "Notepad.exe",   //Program path
   "arg1 arg2",     //Command line arguments
   "C:\\",           //Start in what directory
  SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED  //Window state
);
```

As for system(), it only takes one argument which is the same as you would type in the console (cmd.exe)
for example
`system("dir /a");` does exactly the same as typing `dir /a` in cmd.exe

If you have trouble in building in [devC++](http://orwelldevcpp.blogspot.com/) check the project properties.

From 'Project options'>Directories>

- Library Directories `\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib32`
- Include Directories:  `\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include`

From 'Project options'>Parameters> Linker

- `-lshell32`

Comment: Is `windows.h` included in minggw compiler because dev c++ uses that compiler?

Comment: well i can use another ide if you recommend and it creates `.exe` files.

Comment: I think it is. you can search on your computer for that file name. if you find it, you just need to fix the include directories to point to that. I recommend visual C++ express edition for development.

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\windows.h

Answer (score 0):

Did you try CreateProcess ?

```
CreateProcess(lpApplicationName
               NULL, NULL, NULL,
               NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
               lpStartupInfo,
               lpProcessInformation
              )
```

Comment: this should be possible from any Windows C Compiler with windows.h. Here are docs [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx  
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)